# Rails Source Code (summary inference)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can someone explain this piece of Rails Source Code to me? I've highlighted the portions I'm not getting but if you'd like to give a general summary as well that'd be helpful.

```
 def create_record(attributes, raise_error = false)
 record = build_record(attributes)
```

> yield(record) if block_given?

```
 saved = record.save
 set_new_record(record)
```

> raise RecordInvalid.new(record) if !saved && raise_error

```
 record
  end
```

This would especially be helpful to those taking the CodeAcademy course so thanks.

Best Regards

Willke